# Linear perturbations of the energy conservation in FLRW spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, energy-conservation, perturbation-theory

Recently i have some troubles regarding linear stability analysis in GR, especially matter conservation equation.

First order perturbations of the Hubble parameter and energy density are:

$$H=H_b(1+\delta(t)),\qquad\rho=\rho_b(1+\delta_m(t))$$

Using this in conservation equation in the FRW universe (dot is derivative wrt time $t$):

$$\dot{\rho}+3H(1+\omega)\rho=\dot{\rho}_b(1+\delta_m)+\rho_b(1+\dot{\delta}_m)+3H_b(1+\delta)(1+\omega)\rho_b(1+\delta_m),$$

which after discarding terms without perturbations and quadratic in $\delta$'s gives:

$$\dot{\rho}_b\delta_m+\rho_b\dot{\delta}_m+3H_b(1+\omega)\rho_b(1+\delta+\delta_m+\delta_m\delta)= \dot{\rho}_b\delta_m+\rho_b\dot{\delta}_m+3H_b(1+\omega)\rho_b(\delta+\delta_m)$$
However, the correct equation is:
$$\dot{\delta}_m+3(1+\omega)H_b\delta=0.$$

What am I missing? How to derive this relation correctly?
Equation can be found for example in:
https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.02037 (eq 39).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like, that you are almost there. You just have to use the background equation of motion to cancel the remaining terms, ie. 
$$\delta_m\left[\dot{\rho}_b+3H_b(1+\omega)\rho_b\right]=0$$

Comment: Now this makes sense to me. I also have quick question - can i use background equations for more complicated perturbations (for example Friedmann equations in modified gravity theories )? For example: can i get rid of some terms in field equation where i plugged perturbed Hubble parameter $H$ and cancel some terms using analogous field equation for background $H_b$?

Comment: Yes, you can always use the corresponding background equations (which will look more complicated in modified theories) to simplify the equations for the perturbations. You can see it from a different point of view as well: in the example above you just replace the background quantity $\dot \rho_b$ by $-3H_b(1+\omega) \rho_b$, which is a perfectly valid substitution justified by the background equations of motion.